# Is there an URL listing latest posts

Tags: urls, homepage

Currently my homepage is showing my lastest posts but I want to replace it with a page.

I wish that all the posts could still be seen in a widget and by clicking on "news" in the menu.

I already do that for custom types with `http://website.com/customtypename/` which shows all my lastest items. Just by adding this URL to my main menu

Is there the same URL already existing for posts?

Comment: I am guessing [this page from the WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) provides all the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you want to replace your home page with a static front page under Settings > Reading. Then you'll create a new page and set it as your posts page in the same setting. The slug of that new page then determines the URL of the posts page.